# How to send updates when data changes using MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, socket.io

Alright I know you might find this as a silly question, but I'd like to ask you if there's a way to have a listener to MySQL like *Firebase* can do?

*"...Firebase only sends updates to our app when data changes."* - from learnhowtoprogram [article](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-reading-data-and-event-listeners)

To make my question clear, I'm using nodejs, express & socket.io and I really wanted to make a simple web app which will automatically update its data once the database(MySQL) changes.

I've made a prototype using socket.io which listens to the client and emit new data from MySQL and vice versa. Yes, it works but in the long run it's horrible.

I hope you could help me with the concepts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that if you are using nodejs and socket
try this lib : [mysql-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events)

Comment: Thanks MrCharif. I'll check this lib out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to fully utilize mysql-events due to binlog_format is fixed in "row". I don't have the privilege to set the default binlog_format= from "mixed" to "row".